# Selected Rows become unselected after filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have grid view that has check-boxes to select items

how can i filter grid view without losing the items that has been checked.

**Gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridpur" CssClass="table table-bordered text-nowrap" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Pro_ID" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Filter Code**

```
StoreClass s = new StoreClass();
gridpur.DataSource = s.SearchPurchase(hdnSearchParam.Value, txtsearch.Text);
gridpur.DataBind();
```

**Gridview Data Source**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        StoreClass s = new StoreClass();
        gridpur.DataSource = s.getpurchase();
        gridpur.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the state of the checkboxes before you filter, and restore them after, or make the state of the checkbox part of what you are databinding to the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to store your selected checkboxes(the keys which seems to be the `Pro_ID` column/property)  before you `DataBind` it, then select them afterwards again:

In your filter-method:

```
List<string> selectedProIDs = gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => new { 
        CheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSel"),
        ProID = gridpur.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()
    })
    .Where(x => x.CheckBox.Checked)
    .Select(x => x.ProID)
    .ToList();

StoreClass s = new StoreClass();
gridpur.DataSource = s.SearchPurchase(hdnSearchParam.Value, txtsearch.Text);
gridpur.DataBind();

foreach(GridViewRow row in gridpur.Rows)
{
     var checkBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSel");
     string proID = gridpur.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
     checkBox.Checked = selectedProIDs.Contains(proID);
}
```